# Converting list of string into integers and reshaping the original list

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

I have the following list which I am importing from Python - thus the format:

```
l = {{"a", "[1,2,3,4,5]"}, {"b", "[6,7,8,9,10]"}}
```

I wonder how can I convert this to the following shape:

```
{{{"a"}, {1,2,3,4,5}}, {{"b"}, {6,7,8,9,10}}}
```

Essentially for each letter the numbers in front should be converted to integer and list so one can do operations on them.

Comment: Can you export Python results to a more standard format?

Comment: How does the Python file looks like in plain text?

Comment: Thanks for accepting Coolwater's  answer, it's a very good answer, but anyhow I think you were too hasty doing that. While *accepting* is one of the [things to do after your question is answered](https://wolfr.am/v57DB3p4), we recommend that users should test answers before [voting](https://wolfr.am/v57ItzJq) and wait 24 hours before [accepting](https://wolfr.am/v57LwTXD) the best one. Even more in this case where there were unresolved questions in the comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way:

```
Replace[l, s_String :> If[StringMatchQ[s, "[" ~~ ___ ~~ "]"],
   ToExpression["{" <> StringTake[s, {2, -2}] <> "}"], {s}], {2}]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
l /. 
  s_String :> StringReplace[s, "[" ~~ st___ ~~ "]" :> ToExpression["{" <> st <> "}"]] /. 
  StringExpression -> Identity /. 
  s_String :> {s}
```

> {{{"a"}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}, {{"b"}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}}}

Also

```
l1 = l;
l1[[All, 1]] = Map[List]@l[[All, 1]];
l1[[All, 2]] = Map[ToExpression@StringJoin["List", #] &]@l[[All, 2]];
l1
```

> {{{"a"}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}, {{"b"}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}}}

```
l2 = StringReplace[#, {"[" -> "{", "]" -> "}"}] & /@ l;
l2[[All, 1]] = List /@ l2[[All, 1]];
l2[[All, 2]] = ToExpression[l2[[All, 2]]];
l2
```

> {{{"a"}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}, {{"b"}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}}}

```
l3 = MapAt[List, l, {All, 1}];
l3 = MapAt[ToExpression@StringReplace[#, {"[" -> "{", "]" -> "}"}] &, l3, {All, 2}];
l3
```

> {{{"a"}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}, {{"b"}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}}}

Answer (score 4):

```
{{#1}, ToExpression@StringSplit[#2,"["|"]"|","]}&@@@l
```

alternatively, using regex:

```
{{#1}, ToExpression@StringSplit[#2,RegularExpression["\W{1}"]]}&@@@l
```

> {{{a}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}, {{b}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}}}